# Why is page tpl not getting detected

Tags: 7, theming

I have a view with page display's page setting as following:

```
Path: some/path
Menu: No Menu
```

However it was overridden in templates by `page--some--path.tpl.php` for styling purposes. This tpl actually overrides `page--some.tpl.php` which is a base tpl for all pages located at `some/*` path.

I have now been asked to change this the path to `some/path2`. I did the same in views page settings. And created a tpl file `page--some--path2.tpl.php`.

Problem is that this tpl file is not getting detected and Drupal is using `page--some.tpl.php` as the template.

Why so?

Comment: Define that template in template.php

Comment: @Manu: How can I do that?

Comment: Have you cleared the cache?

Answer (score 0):

This is the snippet I wrote for  region--login.tpl.php try this once. Hope it meets your requirements.
in template.php

```
 <?php
 function yourthemeName_theme() {
   $items = array();
  // create custom user-login.tpl.php
  $items['user_login'] = array(
  'render element' => 'form',
  'path' => drupal_get_path('theme', 'yourthemeName') . '/templates',
  'template' => 'region--login',
   'preprocess functions' => array(
   'yourthemeName_preprocess_user_login'
   ),
   );
   return $items;
  }
  ?>
```